# Figuring out facebook iFrame clients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

I am in the process of building a facebook app that works through iFrame with Ruby On Rails.

My App does serve multiple clients, web, mobile, and facebook. And depending the type of client the UI renders different kind of views.

When the user connects to my app using the facebook page tab, I do get enough information (in params collection) to identify the user came from facebook. Based on that I can customize the views to fit into the iFrame.

But for subsequent requests, because they happens through iframe, there is nothing that tells this is a facebook request (as far as I can tell unless there is something in the headers which I dont know of).

I tried setting a cookie during the first request and that worked great. But the problem is when the user requested my app directly from another browser tab (not through facebook)  the cookie was still present and the user ended up seeing the facebook(ised) UI, instead of Normal UI.

Anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to solve this with the least amount of intrusion into the existing code.
And am posting my solution here for the benefit of anyone looking to solve similar problem.

I have a unique layout for facebook and this was invoked during the first request (like I mentioned above, the initial request posted from facebook tab has facebook params).
To make sure there was facebook param for subsequent requests, inside the facebook layout, I bound all the form submission and anchor click events to a method that would add a hidden form element and query string param respectively.

this is how the client side code looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {


        $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'fb_param',
    name: 'fb_param',
    value: 'true'
}).appendTo($(this));

     return true;
    });
    $('a').click(function(e) {          
        var newUrl = $(this).attr("href");
        if (newUrl.indexOf("?") != -1) {
            newUrl = newUrl + '&fb_param=true';
        } else {
            newUrl = newUrl + '?fb_param=true';                
        }
        $(this).attr("href", newUrl);
     return true;
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Now to handle the server side redirects (typical when you update a resource etc), needed to extend the redirect_to method like so:

> /app/conntrollers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
    if params[:fb_param] == 'true'  
      if options
        if options.is_a?(Hash)
          options["fb_param"] = "true"
        else
          if options.include? "?" 
            options = "#{options}&fb_param=true"
          else
            options = "#{options}?fb_param=true"
          end 
        end
      end 
    end

    super 

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a different route for Facebook tabs. So if your regular URLs look like this:

```
/foobar
```

Then you may want to use something like this for Facebook, by adding the "/fb" prefix (or similar) to your Facebook app's tab or canvas URL:

```
/fb/foobar
```

In your routes.rb, you can then pass a parameter to indicate that the user is viewing the page on Facebook, such as "channel=facebook" or "facebook=true".

Your routes.rb might look something like this:

```
scope 'fb', :channel => 'facebook' do
    # ... your routes ...
end

scope :channel => 'web' do
    # ... your routes ...
end
```

With these routes, each request originating from Facebook will automatically have a "channel=facebook" parameter. Of course, you'd still be responsible for making sure to generate the appropriate URLs within your app. You could add `:as => 'facebook'` and `:as => web` to the scopes above and use this to generate URLs using dedicated helpers (e.g. `facebook_foobar_url`, `web_foobar_url`). But the best way to do this depends a lot on the complexity of your app.

Alternatively, you could also use `default_url_options` in your controller to add a "channel=facebook" or "facebook=true" parameter to every generated URL if you detect that the current request originated from Facebook (either from the existence of a signed_request or from channel/facebook param you added). Note that this method is deprecated in Rails 3, and I'm not quite sure what (if any) the official replacement is in Rails 3.1 or 3.2.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am little confused on the actual implementation. Should every request contain the facebook=true param?

Comment: Manually adding this param isn't what I had in mind, although it is another option. I have edited to post to add some more details for my original suggestion, as well as an alternative that does involve such a param.

Comment: Mirko, I ended up solving this little differently. please see below for details. +1 and Thanks for your suggestion. It might help someone looking to solve similar issues. Thanks!